# NPM Node Dependency Issue - BigNumber is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am following the Set Protocol Getting Started [tutorial](https://docs.setprotocol.com/#/getting-started#summary). I am familiar with vanilla Javascript, but not with Node, NPM, Webpack etc. I picked up bare minimum info on these and have been trying to run the code described in the tutorial in a browser. You can find the latest code in this github [repo](https://github.com/septerr/setprotocol-tutorial).

index.html has following code:

```
<html>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div>
      Hello World!
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@0xproject/typescript-typings": "^3.0.2",
    "bignumber.js": "^5.0.0",
    "setprotocol.js": "^1.2.9-rc1",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.36"
  },
  "name": "setprotocol",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "set protocol tutorial",
  "author": "swapna",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
      filename: 'main.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
      },
      optimization: {
        minimize: false
    },  
  };
```

I see bignumber.js under `node_modules` in the root of my project:
[image]

I am building main.js by running `npx webpack --config webpack.config.js`

When I load index.html in the browser (running `npm install http-server -g` in the `dist` folder), I see following error in the browser's JS console:

```
main.js:203795 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: BigNumber is not defined
    at createStableSet (main.js:203795)
    at Module.<anonymous> (main.js:203818)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20)
    at main.js:84
    at main.js:87
createStableSet @ main.js:203795
(anonymous) @ main.js:203818
__webpack_require__ @ main.js:20
(anonymous) @ main.js:84
(anonymous) @ main.js:87
```

Code where the error happens:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: Showing the file you are trying to use it in would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the module where you use BigNumber, you need to import it. Eg, if you have

```
// mymodule.js

(async () => {
  const { units, naturalUnit } = await setProtocol.calculateSetUnitsAsnyc(
  componentAddresses,
  [new BigNumber(1), new BigNumber(1)],
  // ...
```

Change it to

```
// mymodule.js

import BigNumber from 'bignumber';

(async () => {
  const { units, naturalUnit } = await setProtocol.calculateSetUnitsAsnyc(
  componentAddresses,
  [new BigNumber(1), new BigNumber(1)],
  // ...
```

Comment: thanks for the info. setprotocol is a dependency which uses bignumber. I think setprotocol must be importing bignumber.

Comment: ah nm! you are right, I am using BigNumber in my JS file as well.

Comment: Adding `import BigNumber from 'bignumber.js'` to my JS file fixed the issue. Thank you!